# creating const lvalue-reference from return by value: how does it work?

Tags: c++, memory-management, g++, stack, rvalue-reference

I've learnt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340925/return-by-value-assigned-to-const-reference) that a const reference can be made out of an object returned by value by a function. But now I asked myself: where does one place this object, so that it is safe and is not overwrote by stacks of future function calls?

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A{};

A returnsmt(){
    int avariable;
    cout<<"returnsmt stack: "<<&avariable<<endl;
    return A();
}

const A& proxyreturnsmt(){
    int avariable;
    const A& middle=returnsmt();
    cout<<"proxyreturnsmt stack: "<<&avariable<<" A ptr: "<<&middle<<endl;
    return middle;
}

int main(){
    int avariable;
    const A& a=proxyreturnsmt();
    cout<<"main stack: "<<&avariable<<" A ptr: "<<&a<<endl;
}
```

Now, it's not even feasible that `main` knows that it's going to create a reference from an object of the stack, so the trick cannot be that it passes a hidden pointer to a free stack bucket of its own. This code on g++ prints:

```
returnsmt stack: 0x7fff3718bc0c
proxyreturnsmt stack: 0x7fff3718bc28 A ptr: 0x7fff3718bc2f
main stack: 0x7fff3718bc4c A ptr: 0x7fff3718bc2f
```

so it looks like, if the stack grows downward, that the place where the object is, is effectively `proxyreturnsmt`'s stack. How come you wouldn't run into troubles if after getting this reference, you call, let's say, `function_with_big_stack_alloc`, and so certainly reclaim the old `proxyreturnsmt`'s stack for new usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program exhibits undefined behavior.  In `proxyreturnsmt`, you bind `middle` to a temporary object.  The lifetime of that temporary object is extended only until `middle` goes out of scope.

You then return a reference to `middle`; but the object to which it refers is destroyed as the function returns.  So, in `main`, where you bind `a` to the result of calling `proxyreturnsmt`, `a` is a dangling reference (the object to which it refers no longer exists).

When you attempt to use the reference (by taking the address of the referenced object that no longer exists), the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: I wonder why g++ does not complain about it. I think that it can easily enforce `middle` not to be returned.