# Is reference binding to a temporary of a temporary undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, reference, lifetime

In the following the snippet, is the lifetime of the sphere extended in such a way that the value of `r` is not undefined?

```
 struct Sphere {
   auto& radius() const { return _radius;}
   float _radius{};
 };
 struct Capsule {
   auto sphere() const { return Sphere{12.0}; }
 };
 auto func() {
   auto capsule = Capsule{};
   const auto& r = capsule.sphere().radius();
   std::cout << r;
 }
```

I know that const-references extend the life time of a temporary, but I'm not sure what happens if a member of a temporary is bound to.

*Note: I'm very suspicious that the equivalent of this snippet is causing a bug for me, but neither Clang nor Visual Studio issues a warning.*

Comment: Same thing as what I observed in [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38339023/1896169). I think there's a dupe somewhere...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [const reference to a temporary object becomes broken after function scope (life time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236007/const-reference-to-a-temporary-object-becomes-broken-after-function-scope-life)

Comment: In this case, yes `r` is dangling. The lifetime of the object returned from `sphere()` is not extended to the entire lifetime of `r`

Comment: @Justin Yes, technically a duplicate but I think the problem is easier to grasp in this question as it does not involve std::map

Comment: This is some of similar with
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374468/stringstream-string-and-char-conversion-confusion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for lifetime extension to occur, the reference must bind to a prvalue (which is then materialized into a temporary object so that the reference has something to bind to). However, `capsule.sphere().radius()` is not a prvalue; it is an lvalue that refers to `Sphere::_radius`. Therefore lifetime extension does not occur, and the `Sphere` object together with its `_radius` member will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression.

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of the temporary `Sphere`-object is extended only until the completion of the full expression containing the call. The full expression is `const auto& r = capsule.sphere().radius();` and not longer, such that `r` lives longer than the full expression and it's temporary. So I'd clearly vote for undefined behaviour.